# How to let my web-user-control determine automatically the url of the page where it's placed

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
        <asp:HyperLink 
        ID="hyper1"
        runat="server"
        NavigateUrl='<%#string.Format("~/PLayer.aspx?ID={0}&Type={1}",Eval("arrange_by_id"),Eval("value"))%>'><%# Eval("value")%></asp:HyperLink>
```

I've implemented this string format in my NavigateUrl to pass a dynamic querystring depending on the clicked item!

but you see the first part in the string format where it says "~/PLayer.aspx" i want the user control to automatically change this part according to where it's placed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

```
NavigateUrl='<%#string.Format("{2}?ID={0}&Type={1}",
     Eval("arrange_by_id"),Eval("value"), Page.ResolveUrl("~/Palyer.aspx"))%>'
```

Comment: what does Page.ResolveUrl("~PLayer.aspx") output ?
I don't think it's the right format, because the PLayer.aspx is exactly what will change, as the control might be placed in ~/PLayerNEW.aspx for example! so how come it's constant!

Comment: ok, rather than the Page.ResolveUrl(..) try Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath

Comment: Worked Like a charm :D..please update your answer to be accessible to other users...MARKED AS ANSWER

Answer (score 1):

try this
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/resolveurl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could try Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"], it will return the name of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to move the user control from place to place. You can only get the name of the current page from either `Request.Url`, `Request.RawUrl` or `Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"]`.

You can dynamically register user control to change the path when you want it like that. For a reference on dynamically registering user control [see this](http://aspalliance.com/565)

Comment: You got me wrong! I don't need to move the control from one place to another!...I've created a control which will be used in more than one page, so I'll refrence it more than once, what I need to do is to change the code "~/PLayer.aspx" to be automatically adjusted to  ~/any_dir/any_page.aspx (fitch the url of the page where it's refrenced, instead of creating a control for ~/PLayer.aspx and another one for ~/NewFolder/PLayerNew.aspx, etc) u got me ?